# Fatal error: Interface 'JsonSerializable' not found in Cakephp

Tags: php, json, cakephp

I'am getting below error. Please assist me in resolving this.

```
Fatal error: Interface 'JsonSerializable' not found in /home/onliuzgx/xyz.com/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Mailer/Email.php on line 51
```

Answer (score 0):

First you check your PHP version [Cakephp requires 5.6.0](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html) or greater (including PHP 7.2).

If you have proper PHP versoin you check your php.info Settings, if **JSON is Enabled**.

It will resolve the issue

Comment: I use PHP Version 7.0.33

Comment: and --enable-json=shared